# Get username from database to display in textbox

Tags: php, html

I can't seem to display my username from my database into the textbox. These are my codes:

```
$con = new mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

$username = $_GET['username'];
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{
    die("Error: Data not found..");
}
$test = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$username=$test['username'];
```

input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=" echo $username;?>"

Comment: You seem to mix up both OO PHP and normal PHP. Remove the `new`. And make it like `mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Kind of a strange usage case, `username='$username'` and `SELECT username`, you already knew the username.. `mysqli_query` requires a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix up both OO PHP and normal PHP. Follow these steps:

1. Use error handling.
2. Remove the `new`.
3. Make the connection like `mysqli_query($con, $query);`.
4. Sanitise the inputs.

Your full code should be:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "") or die("Cannot Connect! Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['username']);
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (!$result && mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1)
    {
      die("Error: Data not found..");
    }
    $test = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $username = $test['username'];
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
```

Comment: why my textbox is unable to display on the page?

Comment: @prozcay Is this working for you? Coz your code has lots of errors.

Comment: the username is still blank.

Comment: @prozcay Do you get errors? Can you update the question with the current code? Just add it at the end. Don't delete the old contents.

Comment: The username can be displayed in the textbox only when i manually key in the http://....php?username=john.

Comment: @prozcay Yes, that is what the expected behaviour too: `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['username']);`. But what are you expecting to happen?